# Collapse by the maximum

Tags: r

I have a `data frame`, (I just show the tail of the `df`) This data frame is called `conv2`

```
8464   208394_x_at                   ESM1                          -1.035878e-01
8468   200858_s_at                SNORD55                          -1.034971e-01
8469   200858_s_at               SNORD38B                          -1.034971e-01
8467   200858_s_at                   RPS8                          -1.034971e-01
8472     207381_at                   RPS8                          -1.034510e-01
8477   211197_s_at                 ICOSLG                          -1.033752e-01
```

What I want is, whenever there is a name repeated in the second column such as `RPS8` to remove all lines containg such name except for the one with the highest absoulte value for the third column. So in the example row `8467` would be removed.

I have done this way

```
for (d in dup){

  conv2 <- rbind(conv2, conv[which(conv$SYMBOL == d),][which.max(abs(conv[which(conv$SYMBOL == d),][,3])),])

}
```

Is there a better and faster way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R solution that uses the "split-apply-combine" methodology.

```
# split data.frame by column 2
myList <- split(conv2, conv2$col2)

# loop through list of data.frames and rbind observations with maximum values
dfNew <- do.call(rbind, lapply(myList, function(i) i[which.max(abs(i$col3)),]))
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
conv2 %>%
    group_by(col1, col2) %>%
    slice(which.max(abs(col3)))
```

A faster option would be

```
conv2 %>%
   group_by(col1, col2) %>%
   arrange(desc(abs(col3))) %>%
   slice(1)
```

---

Or we can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(conv2)[order(-abs(col3)),  .SD[1L], .(col1, col2)]
```

NOTE: The column names should be changed (as it was not showed in the example)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the same logic using for loop you may try this way, but previous OP has shown a simple way rather than using for loops

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = NA, col2 = NA, col3 = NA)
for(i in unique(df$col2)){
  x <- max(df$col3[df$col2==i])
df12 <- unique(df[df$col3==x & df$col2==i,])
df1 <- rbind(df1,print(df12))
df1 <- df1[!is.na(df1$col1),]
}
print(df1)
     col1     col2      col3
2  208394_x_at     ESM1 -1.035878
21 200858_s_at  SNORD55 -1.034971
3  200858_s_at SNORD38B -1.034971
5    207381_at     RPS8 -1.034510
6  211197_s_at   ICOSLG -1.033752
```

## data

```
df <- data.frame(col1 =c("208394_x_at","200858_s_at","200858_s_at","200858_s_at","207381_at","211197_s_at"),
  col2 = c("ESM1","SNORD55","SNORD38B","RPS8","RPS8","ICOSLG"),
  col3 = c(-1.035878,-1.034971,-1.034971,-1.034971,-1.034510,-1.033752),stringsAsFactors=F)
```